# How to Change value of Element using Javascript Selenium C#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

I am new to automation.I am trying to automate a web page, there is one text field in which i have to enter some text, I tried driver.FindElement(By.XPath("Xpath of elemnt").SendKeys("Value"); but this is not working so I tried sending value through Javascript driver.ExecuteJavaScript("arguments[0].value='100';", 'Element path'); which is working fine.
But this element require actual keystrokes to Identify value of element is changed or not. In shot even if I have entered text in the field page is still considering field as blank.
Can someone help me with the same.

Comment: Can you provide link or more details so we can actually check what can be done?

Comment: I cannot share web site link as it is internal to my company. What else should I share that may be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke a key press event on the element (or whatever event triggers the element state to change).

Something like this:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {'key':'a'}));")
```

Comment: I am Sorry I am new to this so I tried using above code and getting following error "{"Error from JavaScript: Unable to get property 'dispatchEvent' of undefined or null reference"}"   event on field is triggered if i press any numeric key. Could you please help me with suitable code for the same.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add locator of the element earlier. Corrected code is ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {'key':'49'}));", Xpath of element); Now I am getting following error:- {"Error from JavaScript: Object doesn't support this action"}

Comment: Below is the HTML code for the field before Manual Keypress/Click:-
<input class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" type="text" maxlength="10" placeholder="Field Name XYZ" _ngcontent-c8="" formControlName="FieldNameXYZ" numbersOnly="">
                 After Manual Click:
<input class="form-control ng-invalid ng-dirty ng-touched" type="text" maxlength="10" placeholder="Field Name XYZ" _ngcontent-c8="" formControlName="FieldNameXYZ" numbersOnly="">

Comment: After Entering Manual Numeric Value:
<input class="form-control ng-dirty ng-touched ng-valid" type="text" maxlength="10" placeholder="Field Name XYZ" _ngcontent-c8="" formControlName="Field Name XYZ" numbersOnly="">
PLease let me know in case I need to share anything else that could help.